# Drive Letter Change - Reregister VDI for VirtualBox VM

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox

Today, I was trying to get on my Kali Linux virtual machine to just do a basic vulnerability check on a VPS I own. I have my Kali Linux Virtual Disk Image (VDI) saved on a USB external drive, so I plugged that in, fired up Virtual Box, but I got an error when I went to start it. It would appear that the drive letter for this drive has changed from `F:` to `E:`. Thus, VirtualBox could not retrieve the VDI from `F:\Kali Linux VM\`.

Trying to troubleshoot this on my own, I decided to open up the VM settings, remove the SATA Controller VDI that was registered on the `F:` drive, and then add the VDI from the `E:` drive (same VDI, just a difference in drive letter). That, however, did not go as smoothly as planned. I was able to remove incorrect VDI path without any problems, but when I tried to add the VDI on the proper path, I got the following error:

> Cannot register the hard disk 'E:\Kali Linux VM\Kali Linux.vdi' {6b214e73-ae38-427b-90f8-995c7dd4211c} because a hard disk 'F:\Kali Linux VM\Kali Linux.vdi' with UUID {6b214e73-ae38-427b-90f8-995c7dd4211c} already exists.
>
> Result Code: 
>   E_INVALIDARG (0x80070057)
>   Component: 
>   VirtualBoxWrap
>   Interface: 
>   IVirtualBox {0169423f-46b4-cde9-91af-1e9d5b6cd945}
>   Callee RC: 
>   VBOX_E_OBJECT_NOT_FOUND (0x80BB0001)

It looks like I cannot add the VDI back to the VM because it is identical to the VDI I removed.

Has anyone else encountered a problem like this? And does anyone have a fix for this so I don't lose all the data on that VM?

Thank you all in advance.

**Note**: *I know this isn't a programming question, so this may be the wrong Stack Exchange. Please let me know if this would be better suited under a different Stack Exchange site.*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Open `Oracle VM VirtuaBox Manager`. Now go to

> File > Virtual Media manager

Under `Hard disks`, select `Kali Linux.vdi`. Right click and `remove` it.

> NOTE: If `remove` is disabled. Click `release` first. Then right click and `remove`.

Now add the VDI `Kali Linux.vdi` again.

Comment: Thanks for your answer/solution. I had entirely forgotten about this question because I asked it so long ago. I ended up working this out by deleting the original Kali Linux Virtual Machine from VirtualBox, creating an entirely new VM using the original Kali Linux ISO, and then choosing the option to include an existing *VDI* file. As a result, I do not know if your solution would work to solve the issue I was experiencing. Regardless, though, I have upvoted and accepted your answer to close this question and show my appreciation for you taking the time respond.